# Test CRUD Web services with Robot Framework

Tags: json, rest, http, robotframework

What would be the simplest way to use **Robot Framework** for testing a CRUD (or resource oriented) **Web Service** using **JSON** media type?

Example **Read** interaction:

```
GET /user/666 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com


HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Example **Create** interaction:

```
POST /user HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "firstname":"Webber",
    "lastname":"Jim"
}


HTTP/1.1 201 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "id": 9780596805821,
    "firstname":"Webber",
    "lastname":"Jim"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could use [standard libraries](http://robotframework.org/#test-libraries) and [robotframework-requests](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests) like so:

```
*** Settings ***
Library        Collections
Library        OperatingSystem
Library        RequestsLibrary

*** Test Cases ****
Create User
         Create Session      example    http://example.com
  ${file_data}= 
    ...  Get Binary File     ${RESOURCES}${/}normal_user.json
  ${headers}=
    ...  Create Dictionary   Content-Type    application/json
  ${resp}=
    ...  Post Request        example    /user    data=${file_data}    headers=${headers}
         Should Be Equal As Strings
           ...               ${resp.status_code}  201
         Dictionary Should Contain Key
           ...               ${resp.json()}       id
```